# How to get the number e (2.718) using a random number sensor?

Tags: random, numbers, discrete-mathematics

Is it possible to calculate the number e (2.718) using random numbers?

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193990/approximate-e-using-monte-carlo-simulation

Comment: What do you mean by "random numbers?" What is known about those numbers?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that when you say "using random numbers" you mean "using some sort of random sampling scheme." If you want the exact answer to an infinite number of decimals, the answer is "no, not unless you have an infinite amount of time."  However, we can generate random sequences whose expected value is *e*, and we can assess the sampling error using basic statistics. By increasing the sample size, we can decrease the sampling error to any precision you want as long as you specify your desired confidence level.

[It turns out that if you sum a bunch of random uniform(0,1)'s until the sum exceeds 1, the quantity of uniforms required has an expected value of *e*.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)#Stochastic_representations) We can turn that into a sampling problem by writing a method/function to return the count, and taking the average of the values obtained by calling that method multiple times.

You didn't specify any particular language, so here it is in Ruby (which is practically like pseudocode):

```ruby
require 'quickstats'    # install from rubygems w/ 'gem install quickstats'

def trial  # generate results of one trial
  count = 0
  sum = 0.0
  while sum < 1.0
    count += 1
    sum += rand  # Ruby's rand produces U(0,1) values by default
  end
  return count  # added "return" keyword for non-rubyists' readability
end

stats = QuickStats.new
10_000_000.times { stats.new_obs trial }  # more precision? bump up sample size
puts "Average = #{stats.avg}"
half_width = 1.96 * stats.std_err
puts "CI half-width = #{half_width}"
deviation = (stats.avg - Math::E).abs
puts "    |E - avg| = #{deviation} (should be ≤ half-width 95% of the time)"
```

This runs in under 4 seconds on my laptop and produces outputs such as:

```text
Average = 2.7179918000002234
CI half-width = 0.0005421324752620413
    |E - avg| = 0.0002900284588216451 (should be ≤ half-width 95% of the time)
```

Comment: No, I mean a random numbers. I can paraphrase "How do you get the number e using a coin toss?"

Comment: By the way, if more details are needed to answer the question you intended then you need to edit the question itself, not put additional constraints in comments.

Comment: Coin toss outcomes can be considered as bits, convert heads/tails to 0/1 (or the other way around).  All computers are based on binary, so if your bits are independent and have equal probabilities for 0 or 1, you're practically home free.  Use any of a variety of known techniques to convert them to U(0,1)'s, such as grouping them in word-sized clusters and then dividing by max-int, or grouping them in 53 bit clusters and stuffing them into the mantissa of an IEEE double.  There are tricks to adjust if they're not 50/50 or not serially independent, but that's getting far away from finding *e*.

Comment: I do not impose restrictions in the comments. You misinterpreted "using random numbers" on the example of tossing a coin, I explained that I mean random numbers. The fact that with the help of a coin you can generate a random number is too simple, we should not focus on this.

Comment: Do you understand that generating a Uniform(0,1) ***is*** using random numbers?  If that's not what you mean by your statement, the burden is on you to clarify your intent and the place to do so is in the question itself, not in comments.

Comment: I understand that you are using random numbers from 0 to 1. Formally, you answered correctly, you used random numbers to get the number e. But your answer cannot be considered complete, since there is at least one more method in which using a known number of random numbers.

Comment: @SerhiiOleksenko As a professor with a career doing statistics for over 45 years, I'd love to hear more about this method you're claiming exists.  Here's why I think you're wrong.  If your method is based on using random numbers, your estimator of *e* is a function of those random numbers. Functions of random numbers are themselves random, so they have variability.  If your estimator is unbiased, it will converge asymptotically to *e* as the sample size goes to infinity, but since *e* is irrational your estimator will never equal *e* for any fixed/finite sample size.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s another option. Consider the following probability question: you have a biased coin that comes up heads with probability 1/n. You then flip the coin n times. What is the probability that you never flip heads? Well, that’s the probability that you flip tails n times, which is (1 - 1/n)<sup>n</sup>, which as n tends towards infinity starts to rapidly approach 1/e. You could therefore estimate e by picking some modest value of n, simulating n tosses of a coin that comes up heads with probability 1/n, and seeing whether you never flip heads. The proportion of trials that don’t yield heads will approach 1/e, and from there you can estimate e.

For example, here's Python code to flip a coin with heads probability 1/n a total of n times (done by sampling a uniformly random number between 0 and 1) and see if all of them are tails:

```
from random import random
def one_trial(n):
    for i in range(n):
        if random() < 1 / n:
            return False
    return True
```

We can then run a large number of trials and see which fraction of them are all tails. That fraction will be approximately 1/e, so we just take the reciprocal:

```
def estimate_e(n, num_trials):
    successes = 0
    for i in range(num_trials):
        if one_trial(n):
            successes += 1
    return num_trials / successes
```

Doing this with n = 2<sup>10</sup> and num_trials = 2<sup>20</sup> gave me the estimate

> e ≈ 2.7198016257969466,

which isn't too bad.